# Unmarshal nested JSON with different structure but same keys

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying to unmarshal some nested JSON which looks like:

```
{
    "id": "aRandomId",
    "type": "aRandomType",
    "aRandomField": {
        "type": "someType",
        "createdAt": "2020-07-07T15:50:02",
        "object": "anObject",
        "modifiedAt": "2020-07-07T15:50:02"
    },
    "aParameter": {
        "type": "Property",
        "createdAt": "2020-07-07T15:50:02",
        "value": "myValue",
        "modifiedAt": "2020-07-07T15:50:02"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "GeoProperty",
        "value": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                7.0054,
                40.9999
            ]
        }
    },
     ... other things with type, value ...

    "createdAt": "2020-07-07T15:50:02",
    "modifiedAt": "2020-07-07T15:50:02",
}
```

I would like to get all keys and values which are: type, createdAt, Value (also if they are nested)

Actually, I have 2 structs:

```
type Attribute struct {
    Type       string `json:"type"`
    CreatedAt  string `json:"createdAt"`
    Value      string `json:"value"`
    ModifiedAt string `json:"modifiedAt"`
}

type Entity struct {
    Id        string `json:"id"`
    Type      string `json:"type"`
    CreatedAt string `json:"createdAt"`
    Attribute Attribute
}


in := []byte(buf.String())
    var entity Entity
    err := json.Unmarshal(in, &entity)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    frame.Fields = append(frame.Fields,
        data.NewField("key", nil, []string{"type : ", "createdAt : ", "name : "}),
    )
    frame.Fields = append(frame.Fields,
        data.NewField("value", nil, []string{entity.Type, entity.CreatedAt, entity.Attribute.Value}),
    )
```

The problem is there can be several different Attribute struct andIi can't provide them all.
I would like to display all key (only type, createdAt and Value) in one frame and all their value in another.

Maybe have something like that?

```
type Entity struct {
    attribute List<Attribute>
}
type Attribute struct{
    Type       string 
    CreatedAt  string 
    Value      string 
    ModifiedAt string 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is your goal to only unmarshal keys of interest, and ignore everything else?

Comment: I want to display keys and data of interest so yes only unmarshal keys of interest, and ignore everything else can be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is there can be several different Attribute struct andIi can't provide them all

It looks like your JSON data can have a set of keys with similar values (`Attribute`) and you can't know how many of them might be in the data.

For this case, you can use a `map[string]json.RawMessage` as the starting entity to unmarshal to

```
var e map[string]json.RawMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &e); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

You can then range over the values to see if you can unmarshal them into `Attribute` type

```
for k, v := range e {
    var a Attribute
    if err := json.Unmarshal(v, &a); err == nil {
        log.Printf("Got attribute %s: %s", k, string(v))
    }
}
```

[Run it on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/V5fPc-BV2jA)